# setuid not allowing me to run script as root?

Tags: permissions, chmod, setuid

I wrote this tiny script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -xeuo pipefail
whoami
cd /repo && git fetch origin master && git merge -s recursive -X theirs origin/master
```

And set the `u+s` bit which I thought made it so that when running the script it would run as the user who owns the file:

```
chmod a=,u=rwxs,g=rx /usr/local/bin/force-update-repo
```

But when I switch to `www-data` and try to run it:

```
su www-data -s /bin/bash
```

It seems to run as `www-data` not `root`:

```
force-update-repo
+ whoami
www-data
+ cd /repo
+ git fetch origin master
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I have a process that's running as `www-data` and I want to give them elevated permissions to run this script. How can I do that?

Comment: Thesetuid bit works only for binaries which are executed directly by the kernel. Scripts are **read and run** by the interpreter which means the setuid bit does nothing.

Comment: There is a Well Known Major Security Flaw that comes with setuid interpreter scripts. Modern systems disallow it. `perl`'s `taint` system provides a level of safety.